# Pandas/Python - Dataframe transpose/pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from "df.groupby("symbol").tail(2)" such as below

| ID | symbol | prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BNBBTC | 0.009545 |
| 1 | BNBBTC | 0.009455 |
| 2 | ONEUSDT | 0.220050 |
| 3 | ONEUSDT | 0.220055 |

and I would like to transpose/pivot the data to get

| ID | symbol | Last_Price | Current_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BNBBTC | 0.009545 | 0.009455 |
| 1 | ONEUDST | 0.220050 | 0.220055 |

Is it achievable with Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
new_df = df.groupby('symbol')['prices'].agg(Last_Price='first', Current_Price='last').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    symbol  Last_Price  Current_Price
0   BNBBTC    0.009545       0.009455
1  ONEUSDT    0.220050       0.220055
```

Comment: You might add a solution that computes the same directly from the previous object (OP uses already `df.groupby("symbol").tail(2)`, so this would repeat it twice) ;)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean @mozway - how about you just write it out in your own answer? :)

Comment: @richardec no time now! :O

Comment: Mozway, is partially right.. In my example, I showed only 2 rows. but infact I will have at least 2 rows per symbol. I was user tail(2) to get the last two per group.